# Office Outlook 365 Addin SSO API Permission

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

Is there some one who can really help here?
I can't get anything from **sso.getGraphData** in the office addin generated from Yeoman generator.

Here is my code in ssoauthhelper.js:

```html
export async function getGraphData() {
  try {
    
    let bootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowSignInPrompt: true });
    let exchangeResponse = await sso.getGraphToken(bootstrapToken);
    if (exchangeResponse.claims) {
      // Microsoft Graph requires an additional form of authentication. Have the Office host
      // get a new token using the Claims string, which tells AAD to prompt the user for all
      // required forms of authentication.
      let mfaBootstrapToken = await OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ authChallenge: exchangeResponse.claims });
      exchangeResponse = sso.getGraphToken(mfaBootstrapToken);
    }

    if (exchangeResponse.error) {
      // AAD errors are returned to the client with HTTP code 200, so they do not trigger
      // the catch block below.
      documentHelper.writeDataToOfficeDocument("response");
      handleAADErrors(exchangeResponse);
    } else {

      /*const response = await sso.makeGraphApiCall(exchangeResponse.access_token);
      documentHelper.writeDataToOfficeDocument(response);*/

      const _EndPoint = "/me/messages";
      const _UrlParams = "?$select=receivedDateTime,subject,isRead&$orderby=receivedDateTime&$top=10";
      const response = await sso.getGraphData(exchangeResponse.access_token, _EndPoint, _UrlParams);
      documentHelper.writeDataToOfficeDocument(response);

      sso.showMessage("Your data has been added to the document.");
    }
  } catch (exception) {
    if (exception.code) {
      if (sso.handleClientSideErrors(exception)) {
        fallbackAuthHelper.dialogFallback();
      }
    } else {
      sso.showMessage("EXCEPTION: " + JSON.stringify(exception));
    }
  }
}
```

the code in documentHelper.js:

```html
function writeDataToExcel(result) {
  /*return Excel.run(function (context) {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    let data = [];
    let userProfileInfo = filterUserProfileInfo(result);

    for (let i = 0; i < userProfileInfo.length; i++) {
      if (userProfileInfo[i] !== null) {
        let innerArray = [];
        innerArray.push(userProfileInfo[i]);
        data.push(innerArray);
      }
    }
    const rangeAddress = `B5:B${5 + (data.length - 1)}`;
    const range = sheet.getRange(rangeAddress);
    range.values = data;
    range.format.autofitColumns();

    return context.sync();
  });*/

  return Excel.run(function (context) {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    const rangeHeadings = sheet.getRange("A1:D1");
    rangeHeadings.valueTypes = [["ReceivedDateTime", "subject", "Read?", "ID"]];

    const _Contents = result.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < _Contents.length; i++) {
      if (_Contents !== null) {
        let _TempArr = [];

        _TempArr.push(_Contents[i].receivedDateTime);
        _TempArr.push(_Contents[i].subject);
        _TempArr.push(_Contents[i].isRead);
        _TempArr.push(_Contents[i].id);

        let _Data = [];
        _Data.push(_TempArr);

        const _rangeaddress = `A${2 + i}:D${2 + i}`;
        const _rangedata = sheet.getRange(_rangeaddress);
        _rangedata.values = _Data;
      }
    }

    rangeHeadings.format.autofitColumns();

    return context.sync();
  });
}
```

When i run the add-in, it does not proceed after GET/ auth? as shown in below image.

[image: COmmand Prompt View:]

Here are my permission in the Azure APP Registration:

[image: API Permissions:]

I can't understand what is really happening. When i click on the button in the sideloaded task pane, nothing is sent from the Graph API as shown in the command prompt image. I am really grateful, if someone could point out where the error is.
I have defined the scopes in my manifiest file as well.

[image: Scopes in Manifiest File:]

Please help.

Comment: What client module contains sso.getGraphToken? I'm assuming it is calling your web API to exchange the bootstrap token. Are you using NodeJS or ASP.NET or something else for the back end web server? Have you looked at this sample to see how it is done? https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-OfficeAddins/tree/main/Samples/auth/Outlook-Add-in-SSO

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I use node.js with yeoman generator. I was able to find the source of the error. It is from the method (var IncomingMessage = exports.IncomingMessage = function (xhr, response, mode, resetTimers)) which is called from Response.js is in node_modules -> stream-http -> lib -> response.js. The error is Buffer is not defined. Can you help me in this case? It is being five days now without a help. This addin is calling MS Graph API.

Comment: You need to post all of the code from any modules that may be contributing to the error. But I suspect the issue is not in your node modules, but with the endpoint your calling in your backend to exchange the bootstrap token

Comment: The error is generated from "var IncomingMessage = exports.IncomingMessage = function (xhr, response, mode, resetTimers)" inside response.js file located inside node modules. It is actually abnormal,since the error is generated from below line of code.    "} else if(self.push(Buffer.from(chunk))) {". The exception is, "ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined". In client side debugging under network tab, i verified the received data and everything seems to be correct and normal with valid data.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to show the code that is calling your web API endpoint so viewers can determine more about how you exchange the bootstrap token